# creating ggplot stack bar and trend line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with data frame called `df`:

```
    Date    variable   Value
    1/1/2012 teamA     10
    1/1/2012 teamA     10


    1/1/2012 teamB    10

    1/1/2012 teamC     15

    1/2/2012 teamA    25

    1/2/2012 teamB     30

    1/2/2012 teamC     20
```

And a second data frame called `total`

```
     Date      Total
    1/1/2012   50
    1/2/2012   70
```

I am trying to create a ggplot stack var and draw a trend line for the total on the same graph like this:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=Date, y=Value, fill=(variable))) +
       geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
       theme_bw() + 
       opts(title = "Team Performance") + 
       xlab("Date") + ylab("Score") + 
       geom_smooth(data=Total,
                   aes(Date,Total,group=1), 
                   method="lm", size=2, color="darkblue")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'variable' not found
```

When I do this by itself:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=Date, y=Value, fill=(variable))) +  
geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme_bw()
```

it works

`variable` object is definitely there, any ideas, what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Aesthetics mapped in `ggplot()` cascade down to each layer. That means that `fill = variable` is expected in `geom_smooth` and I'm guessing that there's nothing called `variable` in `Total`. Either move `fill = variable` to `geom_bar` or unmap it in `geom_smooth` with `fill = NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Aesthetics mapped in `ggplot()` cascade down to each layer.

That means that `fill = variable` is expected in `geom_smooth` and I'm guessing that there's nothing called `variable` in `Total`. Either move `fill = variable` to `geom_bar` or unmap it in `geom_smooth` with `fill = NULL`.